# Can cookie size affect loading speed? (PHP)

Tags: php, cookies

My website sets and loads cookies that are 200 characters long. Is this too much? Can it possible affect the loading speed? How much?

Comment: Have you measured with and without the cookies?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Information about cookies is exchanged between the user's browser and the server and therefore does impact the user's response time and loading speed. I'm not quite sure if 200 characters will make a 'huge' impact though. Check the table about cookie size and response time here:

[When the cookie crumbles](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/03/01/performance-research-part-3/).

Hope that helps, good luck.

Answer (score 5):

200 characters is not too much. You didn't specify how many cookies.

Each cookie will add some latency to the request because they need to be sent with each HTTP request.

If you want to know the exact difference, measure the load with and without cookies.